# Преобразование Xml в Json php

Tags: php, json, xml

Как преобразовать xml вида

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="KrdAddressReg">
<resultStatus>Ок!</resultStatus>
<addressArr>
 <Addr>
   <address>текст1</address>
   <idAddress>id1</idAddress>
 </Addr>
 <Addr>
  <address>текст2</address>
  <idAddress>id2</idAddress>
 </Addr>
 <Addr>
   <address>текст3</address>
   <idAddress>id3</idAddress>
</Addr>
<Addr>
  <address>текст4</address>
  <idAddress>id4</idAddress>
</Addr>
</addressArr>
</Response>
```

В JSON вида

```
[
    {id: "id1", value: "текст1"}
    {id: "id2", value: "текст2"}
    {id: "id3", value: "текст3"}
    {id: "id4", value: "текст4"}
]
```

Знаю про xml2json, но не знаю, как убрать из xml лишнее, переименовать элементы, да и вообще привести к нужному виду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

print_r($data);
```